# Where to find sbt-assembly in artifacts repositories online?

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I'm running sbt 0.13.0 and have a project with [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) via:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")
```

Upon executing `sbt assembly` I get the following message:

```
[info] Resolving com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.11.2 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.11.2
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.11.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.11.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/szalwinb/.ivy2/local/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.11.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly_2.10_0.13/0.11.2/sbt-assembly-0.11.2.pom
```

The typesafe repo produces a 404 as does the maven repo. It doesn't exist locally (obviously) which brings me to the last option, the scala-sbt repo.  Sadly, my company's network nanny thinks scala-sbt repo is a file sharing site and blocks access.  To get around this, I currently drop off the company network, do the build and then hop back on.

Is there another repo that houses sbt-assembly? Or is there another version of sbt-assembly that is available on maven or typesafe repos that I can use?

Comment: Why don't you use 0.13.5? There are so many useful features available in the version.

Comment: Is "network nanny" a particular product or a nickname for some IT admin?

Comment: Ah, if she only were an endearing Nanny, with poppy seed kolaches fresh from the oven... Instead she is an overbearing hag protecting us from evils that don't exist.

Comment: IT admins updated their blacklist and I'm good to go now.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7):

The standard repository for plugins (http://repo.scala-sbt.org) basically just mirrors the `sbt/sbt-plugins-releases` repo from [Bintray](http://bintray.com), which is where people usually publish their sbt plugins. See the sbt documentation: [Bintray for plugins](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Bintray-For-Plugins.html).

So you should be able to add that repo directly:

```
resolvers += "Bintray sbt plugin releases"
  at "http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")
```

Comment: If bintray's URL redirection is causing the problem, this suggestion is worth trying.

Comment: repo.scala-sbt.org redirects to bintray and then I hit the net nanny issue.  no love.

Comment: isn't jfrog shutting down bintray? https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Bintray+Migration+Guide @gourlaysama

Answer (score 5):

Typesafe repos were migrated to Bintray - https://www.typesafe.com/blog/migrating-repos-to-bintray

Try adding resolver in your plugins.sbt:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("bintray-sbt-plugins", url("http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find building the plugin locally quite useful in your case. Just `git clone` the repository and `publishLocal` to have the version available in your local Ivy2 repository.

I think the last option with `publishLocal` might be the best workaround (until you've eventually convinced your company's nanny that it is a *right* file sharing site).

Comment: We use Ivy repository with custom layout, which encodes sbt version in, so I'll probably just close such request.

Comment: Right. Forgot about the custom Ivy layout scheme. Answer updated.